# A characterization a measurable spaces with a measure with only two values values $0$ and $\infty$

Tags: measure-theory

Is a characterizations of a measure spaces $(X,{\cal S}, \mu)$ with the properties that $\mu(A)=0$ or $+\infty$ for all $A\in {\cal S}$?

Is it maybe : there exists a measurable $E \in {\cal S}$ such that $\mu(A)=0$ for $A\subset E$, $A\in S$ and $\mu(A)=+\infty$ for the other $A\in{\cal S}$?

Comment: What do you mean by "the other $A$"?

Comment: For such measurable $A$ which are not contain in $E$.

Comment: Let $X=\{1,2,3\}$, $\mathcal S=2^{ X}$, $P(\{1\})=0,P(\{2\})=P(\{3\})=+\infty$. Also, let $A=\{1\}, E=\{1,2\}$. Now, $A\subset E$ and $P(A)=0, P(A')=+\infty$ for all $A'\not =A$ except $P(\emptyset)=0.$

Comment: This is not true even in the case of my example. Perhaps I did not understand well your description of the problem.

Comment: It is not a counterexample. Put $E=\{1\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the construction of such a measure on $\left(X,\wp\left(X\right)\right)$:

Let $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\wp\left(X\right)$ be some collection
and define $\nu_{\mathcal{C}}A:=0$ for each $A$ for wich there is
a countable or finite subcollection $\mathcal{C}'\subseteq\mathcal{C}$
such that $A\subseteq\bigcup\mathcal{C}'$. Define $\nu_{\mathcal{C}}A:=+\infty$
otherwise.

A measure $\mu$ on $\left(X,\mathcal{S}\right)$ with $\mu A\in\left\{ 0,\infty\right\} $
for each $A\in\mathcal{S}$ can be looked at as a measure constructed
as above and restricted to $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{S}$.

Taking
$\mathcal{C}:=\left\{ A\in\mathcal{S}\mid\mu A=0\right\} $ we find
$\mu=\nu_{\mathcal{C}}\upharpoonleft\mathcal{S}$.

If there is a countable or finite subcollection $\mathcal{C}'\subseteq\mathcal{C}$
with $E:=\bigcup\mathcal{C}'=\bigcup\mathcal{C}$ then $\nu_{\mathcal{C}}A:=0$
if $A\subseteq E$ and $\nu_{\mathcal{C}}A:=+\infty$ otherwise.

If conversely there is some $E$ with $\nu A:=0$ if $A\subseteq E$
and $\nu A:=+\infty$ otherwise, then  $\nu=\nu_{\mathcal{C}}$
for $\mathcal{C}=\left\{ E\right\} $.

Such a set $E$ does not necessarily exist. For example let $X$ be uncountable and define $\mu$ onf $\wp(X)$ by setting $A\mapsto0$ if $A$ is countable and $A\mapsto\infty$ otherwise.